# How to use multibiding with a Style Setter

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, multibinding

The alternate row style is defined as:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color,Converter={StaticResource dataToColorConverter}}">
</Style>
```

But I want to update the rowstyle depedninng on multiple values. I want to achieve something like this.

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="Background" >
               <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource  dataToColorConverter}>
               <Binding Path="Color"/>
               <Binding ElementName="myListBox" Path="SelectedItem"/>
               </MultiBinding>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But getting the error "The type 'Setter' does not support direct content."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the `Setter` element doesn't support direct content, you must specify that you are setting the `Value` property (include "<Setter.Value>" in your XAML):

```
<Setter Property="Background" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dataToColorConverter}" >
            <Binding Path="Color" />
            <Binding ElementName="myListBox" Path="SelectedItem" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```